# ArrayList OutOfBounds - Java (Android) programming

Tags: java, android, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

The error from the LogCat output is pointing to line 37 of QuestionView.java which I will comment into the code below.  Below I have 4 snippets of 4 classes.  Also I have the output from the LogCat.

MainMenu.java

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenumain);

    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.categoriesBtn);
    Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.highscoresBtn);
    Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.aboutBtn);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainMenu.this, QuestionView.class);
            startActivity(intent1);  
        }
    });
//more code...
```

Question.java

```
public class Question {
String a1;
String a2;
String a3;
String a4;
int correctAnswer;
String query;

public Question() {
}

public Question(String a1, String a2, String a3, String a4, int correctAnswer, String query) {
    this.a1 = a1;
    this.a2 = a2;
    this.a3 = a3;
    this.a4 = a4;
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    this.query = query;        
}

public String getA1() { return a1; }
public String getA2() { return a2; }
public String getA3() { return a3; }
public String getA4() { return a4; }
public String getQuery() { return query; }
public int getCorrectAnswer() { return correctAnswer; }
  }
```

Quiz.java

```
public class Quiz {
ArrayList<Question> qList = new ArrayList<Question>();
public static ArrayList<Question> tenQs = new ArrayList<Question>(10);

public Quiz() {
    qList.add(new Question("A", "B", "C", "D", 3, "Question 1?"));
    qList.add(new Question("A", "B", "C", "D", 3, "Question 2?"));
    qList.add(new Question("A", "B", "C", "D", 3, "Question 3?"));
    qList.add(new Question("A", "B", "C", "D", 3, "Question 4?"));
    qList.add(new Question("A", "B", "C", "D", 3, "Question 5?"));
    qList.add(new Question("A", "B", "C", "D", 3, "Question 6?"));
    qList.add(new Question("A", "B", "C", "D", 3, "Question 7?"));
    qList.add(new Question("A", "B", "C", "D", 3, "Question 8?"));
    qList.add(new Question("A", "B", "C", "D", 3, "Question 9?"));
    qList.add(new Question("A", "B", "C", "D", 3, "Question 10?"));
    qList.add(new Question("A", "B", "C", "D", 3, "Question 11?"));
    qList.add(new Question("A", "B", "C", "D", 3, "Question 12?"));
    qList.add(new Question("A", "B", "C", "D", 3, "Question 13?"));
    qList.add(new Question("A", "B", "C", "D", 3, "Question 14?"));
}

public void getRandom10() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Question x = qList.get((int) Math.floor((qList.size()+1)*Math.random()));
        if(tenQs.contains(x) == true) {
            i--;
        } else {
            tenQs.add(x);
        }
    }
}

public ArrayList<Question> getTenQs() { 
    return tenQs;
}
  }
```

QuestionView.java

```
public class QuestionView extends Activity {

Quiz quiz = new Quiz();
ArrayList<Question> queries = quiz.getTenQs();

int correctAnswers = 0;
int wrongAnswers = 0;

int answer = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.questionviewmain);

    TextView question = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);

    Button answer1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    Button answer2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    Button answer3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    Button answer4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer4);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        question.setText(queries.get(i).getQuery());  //Error points to here.
        answer1.setText(queries.get(i).getA1());
        answer2.setText(queries.get(i).getA2());
        answer3.setText(queries.get(i).getA3());
        answer4.setText(queries.get(i).getA4());

        answer = queries.get(i).getCorrectAnswer();

        answer1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(answer == 0) {
                    correctAnswers++;
                } else {
                    wrongAnswers++;
                }
            }
        });
//more code...
```

LogCat

```
11-12 00:08:40.983: E/AndroidRuntime(4338): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.QuestionView}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
11-12 00:08:40.983: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-12 00:08:40.983: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-12 00:08:40.983: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-12 00:08:40.983: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-12 00:08:40.983: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 00:08:40.983: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-12 00:08:40.983: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-12 00:08:40.983: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 00:08:40.983: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-12 00:08:40.983: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-12 00:08:40.983: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-12 00:08:40.983: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 00:08:40.983: E/AndroidRuntime(4338): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
11-12 00:08:40.983: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
11-12 00:08:40.983: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
11-12 00:08:40.983: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at com.example.test.QuestionView.onCreate(QuestionView.java:37)
11-12 00:08:40.983: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-12 00:08:40.983: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-12 00:08:40.983: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
```

Any help or input is appreciated!  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Its an Exception. Make sure you are referring an Array item value with properly initialized and has not null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't call your `getRandom10()` method to initialize list.

EDIT
Also you used bad design with class `Quiz`:

1. `tenQs` is `static` list that you fill with data from `non-static` list `qList`.
2. also `tenQs` is `public` that gives possibility to access it directly through class: `Quiz.tenQs`. I suppose to make it `private` and `non-static` and call `getRandom10` inside consturtor to be sure of correct initialization of your `Quiz`.
3. get your random index as:

Code:

```
Random r = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Question x = qList.get(r.nextInt(qList.size()));
    tenQs.add(x);
}
```

I understood. If you use inside `for` condition `< tenQs.size()` this `for` will not be executed cause actual size of `tenQs` is `0` but capacity is `10`. So you must create constant with number of questions in quiz and use it in this `for` loop.

Comment: Found it.  I've combined getTenQs() and getRandomTen() into one method:


    public ArrayList<Question> getRandom10() {
     for(int i = 0; i < tenQs.size(); i++) {
      Question x = qList.get((int) Math.floor((qList.size()+1)*Math.random()));
      if(tenQs.contains(x) == true) {
       i--;
      } else {
       tenQs.add(x);
      }
     }
     return tenQs;
    }


Still not working how it should but at least it runs with no errors!

Comment: Also, not sure why I had tenQs was static.  Must have been something that I was fiddling with a while ago and forgot to change it back.  I just changed it back to non-static.

Comment: You must write `for(int i = 0; i < queries.size(); i++)` inside `onCreate` also as imran mentioned. What don't work?

Comment: When I click the Start button on the MainMenu, a new activity comes up with a TextView and 4 buttons but all of them are empty strings so nothing comes up.  They should be populated from the getQuery(), getA1(), getA2(), getA3() and getA4() but apparently something is not working.

Comment: It worked!  Thank you so much for the help!  It is randomly selecting a question and answers and printing it to the 4 buttons and the textview.  It still is not looping through to a different question when I select an answer but I can work work on that now.

Comment: Do I accept your answer by just clicking Yes on this answer was helpful?  I don't yet have 15 reputation so I cannot click the up arrow at the beginning of your post.

Comment: Click on tick under my answer and good luck with your program)

Answer (score 1):

Change your for loop condition as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < queries.size() ; i++)
```

and make sure you are initialize `queries` ArrayList before using it

Answer (score 0):

qList.size()+1 = 11 so random will give any number between 0 to 10... So it is fine if number is from 0 to 9, but 10 will cause your program to fail....